# How to add many tabs to the tabwidget

Tags: android, tabwidget

Whats the best way to add many tabs to the tadwidget? I need to add at least 7 tabs, and I dont want them to look too tight. Is there some other component to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add as many Tabs as you want to the tab widget
2. Change the tabWidget's Visibility to GONE
3. Now Implement your `nice component` to select a page

   - Every time this `nice component` changes the selection call:

     ```
     tabHost.setCurrentTab(the_page_index);
     ```